# How to do table grouping with Codeigniter, MySQL and HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have MySQL table like this :

```
id            hari     start_jam    end_jam  kode_mk
1              1       08:00:00    09:30:00  AGP20722
2              1       08:00:00    09:30:00  KAM44173
3              2       08:00:00    09:30:00  PAK44964
4              2       08:00:00    09:30:00  PDK10312
5              3       08:00:00    09:30:00  SBD30623
6              3       10:00:00    12:00:00  SBK31943
```

And I want to output with radio button like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h73U.jpg) but in this picture the radio button schedule in different time is not working.

And this is my codes:

```
<table id="miketbl" style="color:black;"><thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Pilih</th>
  <th></th>
  <th>Hari</th>
  <th>Jam</th>
  <th>Kode Mk</th></tr></thead><tbody>

  <?php foreach($arrjdwlklh as $row) { ?><?php if($row['hari']==1) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td data-label="Pilih" align="center">
  <input type="radio" id="ids1" name="ids1[]" value="<?php echo $row['kode_mk']; ?>" class="paddingClass"/>
  </td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="sks1" name="sks1[]" value="<?php echo $this->Modmk->getsksmk($row['kode_mk']); ?>" class="paddingClass"/></td>
  <td data-label="Hari" align="center"><?php echo hari($row['hari']); ?></td>
  <td data-label="Jam" align="center">
  <?php echo $row['start_jam']." - ".$row['end_jam']; ?></td>
  <td data-label="Kode Mk" align="center"><?php echo $row['kode_mk']; ?></td>
  </tr><?php } ?>
  <?php } ?><tr><td></td></tr>

  <?php foreach($arrjdwlklh as $row) { ?><?php if($row['hari']==2) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td data-label="Pilih" align="center">
  <input type="radio" id="ids2" name="ids2[]" value="<?php echo $row['kode_mk']; ?>" class="paddingClass"/>
  </td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="sks2" name="sks2[]" value="<?php echo $this->Modmk->getsksmk($row['kode_mk']); ?>" class="paddingClass"/></td>
  <td data-label="Hari" align="center"><?php echo hari($row['hari']); ?></td>
  <td data-label="Jam" align="center"><?php echo $row['start_jam']." - ".$row['end_jam']; ?></td>
  <td data-label="Kode Mk" align="center"><?php echo $row['kode_mk']; ?></td>
  </tr><?php } ?><?php } ?>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: what is your html looks like?

Comment: @Follio : I don't know to post the all my code in here because too many code :(, how can I show you the code? hmm..?

Comment: Hi mate, I already posted the code please check them. acctually in foreach until the $row['hari'] == 5 but I just show the code until $row['hari']==2.

Comment: i think you don't need array as your name attribute. Just try to replace `name="ids1[]"` with `name="ids1"` and so on.

Comment: Hmm... @Follio : Yeah I think so but acctually, maybe I didn't check for the start_jam and end_jam like I did for $row['hari'], but I don't know how to check them....?

Comment: if each `kode_mk` has only got one (or relate to) `start_jam` and `end_jam` then it would be no problem.

Comment: but what if in one schedule (the same time), there are some subject how should I make the code?

Comment: it all depends on your DB schema